# Can't I use "like" with "in" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve a problem in sqlzoo, We are provided with a table containing country name, continent, area, population and gdp. The question is to show the name and the continent - but substitute Eurasia for Europe and Asia; substitute America - for each country in North America or South America or Caribbean. Show countries beginning with A or B
When I am using the following query then it is working fine:

```
select name, case 
when continent in ('europe', 'asia') then 'Eurasia'
when continent in ('north america', 'south america', 'caribbean') then 'America' else continent end as continent 
from world where name like 'A%' or name like 'B%'
```

but if want to use the following code then it is not working:

```
select name, case 
when continent in ('europe', 'asia') then 'Eurasia'
when continent in ('north america', 'south america', 'caribbean') then 'America' else continent end as continent 
from world where name like in ('A%', 'B%')
```

The only difference is I am putting the names in a single bracket. Can I not use the "like" with "in"?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. `LIKE` and `IN` are different operators. You can't combine them the way you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` only works with constants (strings, dates, numbers).

You can do what you want with regular expressions:

```
where name regexp '^[AB].*$'
```

Note:  You can simplify this to `name regexp '^[AB]'` because regular expressions look for a match anywhere in the string.  However, I like to keep the semantics the same as `like` when using regular expressions in SQL, so I force the match to the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix the two like that, but you can put the various `LIKE` patterns into a table (temporary table if that is appropriate for what you're doing) and then `JOIN` off of that:

```
SELECT
    name,
    case
        when continent in ('europe', 'asia') then 'Eurasia'
        when continent in ('north america', 'south america', 'caribbean') then 'America'
        else continent
    end as continent
FROM
    World W
INNER JOIN Name_Patterns NP ON W.name LIKE NP.name_pattern
```

`Name_Patterns` would just need a single column that has rows for each pattern that you want to search on. If those change for each call then a temporary table is probably appropriate, built on the fly. If these are configured ahead of time then an actual table makes more sense.

If your patterns are limited to one or two then you're probably better off just building out the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    name,
    case
        when continent in ('europe', 'asia') then 'Eurasia'
        when continent in ('north america', 'south america', 'caribbean') then 'America'
        else continent
    end as continent
FROM
    World W
WHERE
    (
        W.name LIKE 'A%' OR
        W.name LIKE 'B%'
    )
```